# Unity Script - VideoPlayer Doesn't Pause

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a really simple script where I have a video start playing in Unity on start, and then pause at a specific time in the movie:

```
public class PlayVideoScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Will attach a VideoPlayer to the main camera.
        GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");

        // VideoPlayer automatically targets the camera backplane when it is added
        // to a camera object, no need to change videoPlayer.targetCamera.
        videoPlayer = camera.AddComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();

        // Play on awake defaults to true. Set it to false to avoid the url set
        // below to auto-start playback since we're in Start().
        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;

        // By default, VideoPlayers added to a camera will use the far plane.
        // Let's target the near plane instead.
        videoPlayer.renderMode = UnityEngine.Video.VideoRenderMode.CameraNearPlane;

        // This will cause our Scene to be visible through the video being played.
        videoPlayer.targetCameraAlpha = 0.5F;

        // Set the video to play. URL supports local absolute or relative paths.
        // Here, using absolute.
        videoPlayer.url = "Assets/Movie.mp4";

        // Skip the first 100 frames.
        videoPlayer.frame = 100;

        // Restart from beginning when done.
        videoPlayer.isLooping = false;

        // Each time we reach the end, we slow down the playback by a factor of 10.
        //videoPlayer.loopPointReached += EndReached;

        // Start playback. This means the VideoPlayer may have to prepare (reserve
        // resources, pre-load a few frames, etc.). To better control the delays
        // associated with this preparation one can use videoPlayer.Prepare() along with
        // its prepareCompleted event.
        videoPlayer.Play();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        print(videoPlayer.time);

        print(videoPlayer.time);
        if (videoPlayer.time == 15.0) {
            print("paused;");
            videoPlayer.Pause();
        }

    }
  }
```

I can verify that I've reached the time I want in the `Update` function, but the `videoPlayer` doesn't pause at all. I'm pretty new to Unity, so any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you reached further from one frame to another (as an example : one frame would be 14.8, and the next 15.1). So you never equal 15. Try to do : `if (videoPlayer.time >= 15.0) { ... }`

Comment: @Malphegal ha, that's exactly it --- want to write this as an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Update` method, you check if the video reached exactly 15s.
The thing is, from one frame to another, you may go further than 15 and so never equal 15.

I will suggest you to do as the following :

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (videoPlayer.time >= 15.0) {
        print("paused;");
        videoPlayer.Pause();
    }
}
```